# Contraction Mapping Principle and one-one

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (where U is an open subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{n}$). Assume F satisfies the hypothesis of the contraction mapping principle.
How can we find sets M and N such that $F:M \rightarrow N$ is a one to one map ?

I know that the contraction mapping principle will give us $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$ such that for every y in B(0, $r_{1}$) we have an unique x in B(0, $r_{0}$) and F(x) = y. 
However the problem is that a single x can still map to 2 different y's in the open ball, right ?
Any hints as to how I can choose an interval N such that no 2 y's in that interval have the same x ($\in B(0, r_{0})$) mapping to it ?

Comment: $F$ is a function, which means it takes only one value at any point $x$ in its domain.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ohh..yesss. Thanks ! I guess I was overthinking things and forgot the very fundamentals

Comment: Can you give me any hints as to how I can find sets M and N such the F is one-one from M onto N. My confusion is basically why this relationship does not directly follow from the contraction mapping principle ie. why cant we just take M to be B(0, $r_{0}$) and N to be  B(0, $r_{1}$) ?

Comment: ^ Is it because with the contraction mapping principle we cannot conclude that every x in B(0, $r_{0}$) gets mapped to a value which lies in B(0, $r_{1}$) ?

Comment: If you believe the statement that for every $y \in B(0, r_1)$ there is a unique  $x \in B(0, r_0)$ such that $F(x) = y$, then you can take $M = B(0, r_0) \cap F^{-1}(B(0, r_1))$ and $N = B(0, r_1)$.  $M$ and $N$ are open since $F$ is continuous (I assume this was a requirement - otherwise just take one point sets), $F$ maps $M$ into $N$ by construction, and $F$ is one-to-one since $x$ is unique given $y$.

Comment: Thanks ! I thought of the same thing !